# How can I upload a pdf file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have to upload a .pdf file in a web application using the `FileUpload` control. I have tried this code, but it has some problems. Can anyone help me with this?

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
      {
           if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == ".pdf")
           {
                string path = Server.MapPath(".") + "\\" + FileUpload1.FileName;
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(path);
                Label6.Text = "File Uploaded Successfully...";
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FileUpload1.FileContent);
                string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
           }
           else
                Label6.Text = "Upload .pdf File";
      }
      else
           Label6.Text = "Upload file";
 }
```

Comment: ContentType != File extension

Comment: the program is directly goin to else statement its not executing the other statements

Comment: Yes, it is, because ContentType will never be ".pdf", as that is a file extension and not a content type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should restructure your code so that it can tell you exactly what's wrong with the upload. Something like this:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Label6.Text = ProcessUploadedFile();
 }

 private string ProcessUploadedFile()
 {
    if(!FileUpload1.HasFile)
        return "You must select a valid file to upload.";

    if(FileUpload1.ContentLength == 0)
        return "You must select a non empty file to upload.";

    //As the input is external, always do case-insensitive comparison unless you actually care about the case.
    if(!FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType.Equals("application/pdf", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return "Only PDF files are supported. Uploaded File Type: " + FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;

    //rest of the code to actually process file.

    return "File uploaded successfully.";
 }
```

My guess is that the browser is not supplying correct content/type. Try the above code and tell us the message you get.

Comment: yes this wrkng fine for me ty....i have a "Show File"(Hyper link button) on the web page when i click on that it should show the pdf file how can i do that

Comment: I am not able to make sense of your comment. Can you ask your question again?

Comment: fileupload( to upload file)                       showfile(Hyperlink)
   submit(button click)                                               this is how my web page looks when i click on "showfile" link it should show me the pdf file i had upoaded

Comment: In that case, you will have to associate the uploaded file with the user and save the file path details somewhere. This can not be explained in a comment, please open another question to get a detailed answer.

Comment: m not able ask any mre questions can u give me the answer  here plz

Answer (score 3):

```
<INPUT id="FileUp" type="file" name="File1" runat="server">

      if(FileUp.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUp.PostedFile.FileName);
            if(ext=="pdf"){
            string Filename=YourFileName+ext;
            FilePath=Server.MapPath("..") + "\\path\\toyourfile\\" + Filename;
            FileUp.PostedFile.SaveAs(FilePath);
            Label6.Text = "File Uploaded Successfully...";
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 3):

**You just replace your below code line**

```
if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == ".pdf")
```

**with this**

```
if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/pdf")
```

and your code is working fine.

Comment: I did copy of your code just change this line and it's working in my environment.

Comment: i mean the execution point is directly goin to else statement

Comment: yup its wrkng fine nw ty.......i have a "Show File"(Hyper link button) on the web page when i click on that it should show the pdf file how can i do that