# ASP.NET converting .doc to .pdf relative pathing mapping fail

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

Whenver I upload a file I want to have it automatically converted into
.pdf (I am doing that using NuGet). The thing is the upload scheme is done using
relative pathing. I do now know what to put into this parantheses:
var wordDocument = appWord.Documents.Open(uploadedFile);
This gives a null exception; saying that the file has NOT been found.
NOTE that the uploading code , without the conversion part, is working flawlessly.

What should I replace uploadedFile with in order to work? I will leave my
realtive path mapping code below so you can see everything that I have done
in order to better help you (and me as well) with what should be put into
that parantheses in order to work? Thank you so much!

````
public IActionResult Index1()
        {
            // Get files from the server
            var model = new FilesViewModel();
            foreach (var item in Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "upload")))
            {
                model.Files.Add(
                    new FileDetails { Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item), Path = item });
            }
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index1(IFormFile[] files)
        {
            // Iterate each files
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                // Get the file name from the browser
                var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                // Get file path to be uploaded
                var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "upload", fileName);

                

                // Check If file with same name exists and delete it
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
                }

                // Create a new local file and copy contents of uploaded file
                using (var localFile = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(filePath))
                using (var uploadedFile = file.OpenReadStream())
                {
                    var appWord = new Application();
                    if (appWord.Documents != null)
                    {
                        //yourDoc is your word document
                        var wordDocument = appWord.Documents.Open(file) ;
                        string pdfDocName = "pdfDocument.pdf";
                        if (wordDocument != null)
                        {
                            wordDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(pdfDocName,
                            WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);
                            wordDocument.Close();
                        }
                        appWord.Quit();
                    }


                    uploadedFile.CopyTo(localFile);





                }
               
            }
            ViewBag.Message = "Files are successfully uploaded";

            // Get files from the server
            var model = new FilesViewModel();
            foreach (var item in Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "upload")))
            {
                model.Files.Add(
                    new FileDetails { Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item), Path = item });
                
            }
            return View(model);
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Download(string filename)
        {
            if (filename == null)
                return Content("filename is not availble");

            var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "upload", filename);

            var memory = new MemoryStream();
            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
            }
            memory.Position = 0;
            return File(memory, GetContentType(path), Path.GetFileName(path));
        }
        private string GetContentType(string path)
        {
            var types = GetMimeTypes();
            var ext = Path.GetExtension(path).ToLowerInvariant();
            return types[ext];
        }

        private Dictionary<string, string> GetMimeTypes()
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {".txt", "text/plain"},
                {".pdf", "application/pdf"},
                {".doc", "application/vnd.ms-word"},
                {".docx", "application/vnd.ms-word"},
                {".xls", "application/vnd.ms-excel"},
                {".xlsx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"},
                {".png", "image/png"},
                {".jpg", "image/jpeg"},
                {".jpeg", "image/jpeg"},
                {".gif", "image/gif"},
                {".csv", "text/csv"}
            };
        }```
````

Comment: I think you didn't specify the extension of PDF and the mini type of the file as well from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411119/how-can-i-upload-a-pdf-file you can find that you should specify the "content/type" of file

Comment: Will look rn into it, thanks man! will let you know if i succed

Comment: Oh, no, but I did specify in the dictionary at the end of the code you see:( I strongly believe that this is a pathing problem...

Answer (score 2):

````
//Get the path of existing Word document
string fullpath = @"...\..\DocToPDF.docx";

//Loads an existing Word document
WordDocument wordDocument = new WordDocument(fullpath, FormatType.Docx);

//Creates an instance of the DocToPDFConverter
DocToPDFConverter converter = new DocToPDFConverter();

//Converts Word document into PDF document
PdfDocument pdfDocument = converter.ConvertToPDF(wordDocument);

//Releases all resources used by DocToPDFConverter
converter.Dispose();

//Closes the instance of document objects
wordDocument.Close();

//Saves the PDF file 
pdfDocument.Save("DocToPDF.pdf");

//Closes the instance of document objects
pdfDocument.Close(true);```

this is the NuGet documentation they had on the site, I have got problems at the 2nd row : on specifying the full path
````